# Conjecture: $-\partial_b F(b-a,b-a;b;z)$ is increasing in $z$ (proof of special case provided in answers)

Tags: power-series, hypergeometric-function, monotone-functions

*See answers below for a proof of a special case to the following conjecture.*

I am looking to prove the following conjecture:

> **Conjecture:**
> Let $0<b<a<b+1$. Then,
> $$
> f(z):=-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm db}{_2F_1}\left({b-a,b-a\atop b};z\right)
> $$
> is positive and strictly increasing on $z\in(0,1)$.

I have successfully shown for all $a,b>0$ and $z\in(0,1)$ that $\operatorname{sign}(f(z))=\operatorname{sign}(b-a)$, which gives the necessary result for the first part of the conjecture. However, I have been unable to establish monotonicity in $z$ for the full domain of $a$. So is this conjecture indeed true? The proof below shows that $f>0$ for $b<a<b+1$ and I believe it contains clues for establishing that $f$ is also increasing in $z$ (it does...see answer below for special case).

**Proof that $f>0$ for $0<b<a<b+1$:**

Using [DLMF 15.8.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E1) we write
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(z)
&=-\partial_b F(b-a,b-a;b;z)\\
&=-\partial_b (1-z)^{2a-b}F(a,a;b;z)\\
&=(1-z)^{2a-b}(Q_2-Q_1),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $Q_1=-\log(1-z)F(a,a;b;z)$ and $Q_2=-\partial_b F(a,a;b;z)$. Upon inspection of their power series expansions in $z$, both $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ have nonnegative coefficients and thus are positive on $z\in(0,1)$. Therefore, all we need to show is is $Q_1<Q_2$. Using the series expansion for the logarithm and hypergeometric function we find for the product
$$
Q_1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(a)_k^2}{(b)_k}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}\frac{(a+k)_{-\ell-1}^2}{(b+k)_{-\ell-1}(k-\ell-1)!}\frac{1}{\ell+1}z^k,
$$
where $(a)_n:=\Gamma(a+n)/\Gamma(a)$ is the Pochhammer symbol (rising factorial). The series coefficients are positive and $(x+k)_{-\ell-1}$ is a positive decreasing function in $x$ on $x\in\Bbb R^+$. Since $0<b<a$ it follows that $0<(a+k)_{-\ell-1}<(b+k)_{-\ell-1}$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
Q_1%
&<\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(a)_k^2}{(b)_k}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}\frac{(b+k)_{-\ell-1}}{(k-\ell-1)!}\frac{1}{\ell+1}z^k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(a)_k^2}{(b)_k\,k!}(\psi(b+k)-\psi(b))z^k\\
&=Q_2,
\end{aligned}
$$
with $\psi(z):=\partial_z\log\Gamma(z)$ is the digamma function. The proof is now complete. $\quad\square$

Comment: Are those subscripts falling factorials ?

Comment: @mick $(a)_n:=\Gamma(a+n)/\Gamma(a)$ denotes the rising factorial (Pochhammer symbol). I will add to question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\pFq}[5]{{_{#1}F_{#2}}\left({#3\atop #4};#5\right)}$
I was able to find a proof that holds for the special case: $b+\color{red}{1/2}\leq a<b+1$. As you will see in the proof, there is only one step that introduces the restriction $b+1/2\leq a$ and my hope is someone can improve on this step to prove the conjecture in the affirmative. I will point out this step in the proof by highlighting it in red. Intuition tells me [this](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/16/02/01/) may come in handy for a proof of the general case of the conjecture. We need two lemmas and then the proof will follow.

> **Lemma 1:** For $x>0$, $k\in\Bbb N$, and $\ell=0,\dots,k-1$:
> $$
> (x+k+1/2)_{-\ell-1}^2\leq(x+k)_{-\ell-1}(x+k+1)_{-\ell-1}.
> $$

**Proof:** The proof is conducted by minimizing $g(a)=(x+k+a)_{-\ell-1}(x+k+1-a)_{-\ell-1}$ on $a\in[0,1]$. One can easily show that $g^\prime(1/2)=0$ and $g^{\prime\prime}(1/2)>0$. $\quad\square$

> **Lemma 2:** For $x>0$ and $k\in\Bbb N$:
> $$
> \sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}\frac{(x+k)_{-\ell-1}}{(k-\ell-1)! (\ell+1)}=\frac{\psi(x+k)-\psi(x)}{k!},
> $$
> where $\psi(z):=\partial_z\log\Gamma(z)$ is the digamma function.

> **Theorem:** Let $b+\color{red}{1/2}\leq a<b+1$. Then $\partial_z f>0$ on $z\in(0,1)$.

**Proof:** Using the definition of $f(z)$ and the hypergeometric transformation of [DLMF 15.8.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E1) we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_z f(z)%
&=-\partial_b\partial_z\pFq{}{}{b-a,b-a}{b}{z}\\
&=-\partial_b\frac{(b-a)^2}{b}\pFq{}{}{b+1-a,b+1-a}{b+1}{z}\\
&=-\partial_b\frac{(b-a)^2}{b}(1-z)^{2a-b-1}\pFq{}{}{a,a}{b+1}{z}\\
&=\cdots\\
&=\frac{a-b}{b}(1-z)^{2a-b-1}\left(\left(1+\frac{a}{b}\right)\pFq{}{}{a,a}{b+1}{z}+(a-b)(Q_2-Q_1)\right),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $Q_1=-\log(1-z)F(a,a;b+1;z)$ and $Q_2=-\partial_b F(a,a;b+1;z)$. Using the hypergeometric series, logarithmic series, and Cauchy product of power series we have after some algebraic manipulation
$$
Q_1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(a)_k^2}{(b+1)_k}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}\frac{(a+k)_{-\ell-1}^2}{(b+1+k)_{-\ell-1}(k-\ell-1)!(\ell+1)}z^k
$$
and
$$
Q_2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(a)_k^2}{(b+1)_k}\frac{\psi(b+1+k)-\psi(b+1)}{k!}z^k.
$$
Both $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ have positive coefficients so that $Q_1,Q_2>0$ on $z\in(0,1)$. Furthermore, noting that $(x+k)_{-\ell-1}$ is positive and decreasing in $x$ one can show that $Q_2-Q_1<0$. Thus, our goal will be to bound $\partial_z f$ from below by bounding $Q_2-Q_1$ from below and then showing that this lower bound for $\partial_z f$ is positive.

$\color{red}{\text{If we restrict $b+1/2\leq a<b+1$}}$ then we may use the monotony of $(x+k)_{-\ell-1}$ and Lemma 1 to write
$$
\begin{aligned}
Q_1%
&<\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(a)_k^2}{(b+1)_k}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}\frac{(b+k)_{-\ell-1}(b+k+1)_{-\ell-1}}{(b+1+k)_{-\ell-1}(k-\ell-1)!(\ell+1)}z^k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(a)_k^2}{(b+1)_k k!}(\psi(b+k)-\psi(b))z^k\\
&=:Q_1^\ast.
\end{aligned}
$$
It follows using the recurrence relation for the digamma function that
$$
\begin{aligned}
0 &>Q_2-Q_1\\
&>Q_2-Q_1^\ast\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(a)_k^2}{(b+1)_kk!}\left(\frac{1}{b+k}-\frac{1}{b}\right)z^k\\
&=-\frac{a^2 z}{b(b+1)^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a+1)_k^2}{(b+2)_kk!}\frac{b+1}{b+k+1}z^k\\
&=-\frac{a^2 z}{b(b+1)^2}\pFq{3}{2}{b+1,a+1,a+1}{b+2,b+2}{z}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Now using the integral representation in [DLMF 16.5.2](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.5.E2) we write
$$
\begin{aligned}
Q_2-Q_1^\ast%
&=-\frac{1}{b}\int_0^1 t^b \frac{a^2 z}{b+1}\pFq{}{}{a+1,a+1}{b+2}{zt}\,\mathrm dt\\
&=-\frac{1}{b}\int_0^1 t^b \partial_t\pFq{}{}{a,a}{b+1}{zt}\,\mathrm dt\\
&=\text{IBP}\cdots\\
&=-\frac{1}{b}\pFq{}{}{a,a}{b+1}{z}+\int_0^1 t^{b-1} \pFq{}{}{a,a}{b+1}{zt}\,\mathrm dt\\
&=-\frac{1}{b}\pFq{}{}{a,a}{b+1}{z}+\frac{1}{b}\pFq{3}{2}{b,a,a}{b+1,b+1}{z},
\end{aligned}
$$
Substituting this result into the expression for $\partial_z f$ and simplifying we find
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_z f%
&>\frac{a-b}{b}(1-z)^{2a-b-1}\left(\left(1+\frac{a}{b}\right)\pFq{}{}{a,a}{b+1}{z}+(a-b)(Q_2-Q_1^\ast)\right)\\
&=\frac{a-b}{b}(1-z)^{2a-b-1}\left(2\pFq{}{}{a,a}{b+1}{z}+\frac{a-b}{b}\pFq{3}{2}{b,a,a}{b+1,b+1}{z}\right)\\
&>0,
\end{aligned}
$$
since all terms are positive. $\quad\square$

**All that is needed is to correct the one step that introduces the restriction on $a$.**